# Is there a way to split an array of objects in Rails by two different delimiters?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to do something like this:

```
@residenciais, @comerciais = TipoImovel.all.split { |t| t.residencial? }
```

The problem is that `@comerciais` is always empty because it never returns the object, since the condition is false.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: `all` implies you're using an Active Record query, which, for a large table, will be very inefficient as it will return all records. Tables always grow and over time that will slow your system. I'd consider writing that as two separate queries and possibly iterate over each query's results. It'd be more scalable.

Comment: IF the goal is to have two arrays which together contain all the records, then it's more efficient to fetch them from the database in a single query than separate ones.  If the processing can be done without grabbing all of them into memory at once, then obviously that would be better..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for the standard method [`Enumerable#partition`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition), rather than the Rails `split` add-on.

```
@residenciais, @comerciais = TipoImovel.all.partition { |t| t.residencial? }
```

Which can also be written like this, since the condition is a single method call:

```
@residenciais, @comerciais = TipoImovel.all.partition(&:residencial?)
```

Some more explanation:

The Rails `Array#split` method is used to separate an array into ordered groups delimited by elements which return true for a given block.  It's a generalization of the standard String method. For example:

```
 [1,2,3,4,5,6].split(&:odd?) #=>  [[], [2], [4], [6]]
```

Any odd number is a delimiter, so it returns the portions of the array between the odd numbers, in order.

Whereas this is closer to what you're doing:

```
odds, evens = [1,2,3,4,5,6].partition(&:odd?) #=> [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
```

If the partition condition is not simply Boolean, or if you want to key off the values regardless, then you can use [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), which returns a Hash of Arrays instead of a pair:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6].group_by(&:odd?) #=> {true=>[1, 3, 5], false=>[2, 4, 6]}
```

Comment: I completely forgot about partition. I was struggling to remember and been using split all over. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `group_by`:

```
@residenciais, @comerciais = TipoImovel.all.group_by { |t| t.residencial }.values
```